# c# Wpf Как получить Item из Listbox'а через кнопку?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ListBox, который берет ItemSource из вьюмодели. В ItemTemplate есть 2 кнопки, 
проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопки выделенный item не меняется.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/> <!--Text-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/> <!--Splitter-->

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> <!--Time-->

                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/> <!--Done-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/> <!--Edit-->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="45" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="40" Grid.Column="2" />

            <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="✓" Click="OnCompleteBtnClick"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="4" Content="..." />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Как получить Item из селектора с помощью кнопки из ItemTemplate, если Item не выделен?

Comment: Как? Использовать MVVM, команды, привязки.

Comment: про связку mvvm + wpf + c# на metanit.com есть справочная инфа хорошая)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел метод IndexOf в ListBox.Items, он возвращает индекс конкретного элемента.

```
    private void OnCompleteBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
        int index = data_el.Items.IndexOf(item);

        MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as T, где T - тип вашей коллекции, вы сразу получите свой элемент, без танцев с бубном вокруг индексов. А вообще правильно будет юзать CommandParameter